# office-ui-fabric-react styles combobox label on the left and why the need for !important

Tags: styling, office-ui-fabric

I would like to have the label on the left of the combo box. I am also curious why I need to add the !important to the style to get it to overide the .root style.

```
             <ComboBox
                label='AUDIT Month'
                id='AuditMonth'
                options={this._getMonths()}
                styles={
                  {
                      label:{display:'inline-block !important'},
                      input:{display:'inline-block !important'},
                  }
              }
                defaultSelectedKey=''
                allowFreeform={false}
                autoComplete='on'
            />
```

Above still keeps the .root style and does not put the label where I would like it.

```
            <ComboBox
                label='AUDIT Month'
                id='AuditMonth'
                options={this._getMonths()}
                styles={
                  {
                      label:{color:'fuchsia'},
                  }
              }
                defaultSelectedKey=''
                allowFreeform={false}
                autoComplete='on'
            />
```

And this does not work unless I add !important which I would prefer not to have to do.

Thanks for any help.